# Dropdown Menu showing invisible child boxes but only shows the child text when hovered upon them

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was creating a dropdown menu which when hovered upon displays sub-links.

But, I ran into a problem as when I hover on the dropdown, it shows a blank box and only shows the text when hovered upon it specifically.

I want that the text to be displayed at all times.

```js
// Sticky Navbar
var h = document.getElementById("navbar");
var stuck = false;
var stickPoint = getDistance();

function getDistance() {
  var topDist = h.offsetTop;
  return topDist;
}

window.onscroll = function(e) {
  var distance = getDistance() - window.pageYOffset;
  var offset = window.pageYOffset;
  if ( (distance <= 0) && !stuck) {
    h.style.position = 'fixed';
    h.style.top = '0px';
    stuck = true;
  } else if (stuck && (offset <= stickPoint)){
    h.style.position = 'static';
    stuck = false;
  }
}


// Preloader
const preloader = document.querySelector('.preloader');

const fadeEffect = setInterval(() => {
  // if we don't set opacity 1 in CSS, then   //it will be equaled to "", that's why we   // check it
  if (!preloader.style.opacity) {
    preloader.style.opacity = 1;
  }
  if (preloader.style.opacity > 0) {
    preloader.style.opacity -= 0.1;
  } else {
    clearInterval(fadeEffect);
  }
}, 200);
window.addEventListener('load', fadeEffect);
```

```css
/* Navbar */
#navbar {
  height: 75px;
  display: block;
  background: #333;  
  width: 100%;
}

#navbar a{
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: silver;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 49%;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Navbar -->
<div id="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Projects
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Drum Kit</a>
      <a href="#">Coming Soon...</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Apart from this, I have implemented the Sticky Navbar and a Simple Preloader using **Vanilla JS** which I am sharing if it might help.

Just help me with the dropdown thing.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `#navbar a { color: white }`. Link color is set to white.

Comment: I have tried this but it isn't working. I think my Sticky Navbar JS Code is creating these problems as upon removing that JS Code, the dropdown works fine. 
I think I will have to use JQuery instead of Vanilla JS to implement Sticky Navbar now.
Thanks Anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Y.S. point out you have color set to white. Not sure what you've tried that didn't work, this works fine for me:

```js
// Sticky Navbar
var h = document.getElementById("navbar");
var stuck = false;
var stickPoint = getDistance();

function getDistance() {
  var topDist = h.offsetTop;
  return topDist;
}

window.onscroll = function(e) {
  var distance = getDistance() - window.pageYOffset;
  var offset = window.pageYOffset;
  if ( (distance <= 0) && !stuck) {
    h.style.position = 'fixed';
    h.style.top = '0px';
    stuck = true;
  } else if (stuck && (offset <= stickPoint)){
    h.style.position = 'static';
    stuck = false;
  }
}


// Preloader
const preloader = document.querySelector('.preloader');

const fadeEffect = () => 
{
  setInterval(() => {
    // if we don't set opacity 1 in CSS, then   //it will be equaled to "", that's why we   // check it
    if (!preloader.style.opacity) {
      preloader.style.opacity = 1;
    }
    if (preloader.style.opacity > 0) {
      preloader.style.opacity -= 0.1;
    } else {
      clearInterval(fadeEffect);
    }
  }, 200);
}
window.addEventListener('load', fadeEffect);
```

```css
/* Navbar */
#navbar {
  height: 75px;
  display: block;
  background: #333;  
  width: 100%;
}

#navbar a{
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: silver;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 49%;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
    <!-- Navbar -->
<div id="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Projects
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Drum Kit</a>
      <a href="#">Coming Soon...</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="preloader"></div>
```